# What's the best way to extend the range of a Netgear Orbi mesh network that's in a hub-spoke setup?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, netgear-router

I have an Orbi RBR40 router with 2 satellites, and I'm looking to improve the range without necessarily adding a third satellite. I'm aware of all of the advice on locating the hardware to maximize signal, but that can only get me so far in my situation. I have an detached cottage that I'd like to extend the signal to, but locating a satellite in the cottage doesn't work well; the signal is being interfered with enough that it seems locating it in the main house as close to the cottage as possible is a better solution.

Still, the signal is not as strong as I'd like it to be.

Is there any kind of device (not another satellite) I can use with this Netgear equipment that'll effectively boost the signal to the cottage? Some kind of repeater that will work with the Orbis?

Comment: My recommendation is to buy a spool of outdoor [direct-bury Ethernet](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=direct+bury+etherenet+cable&crid=1OUZFV7LLG7KI&sprefix=direct+bury+ethernet+cable%2Caps%2C79&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) cable, and bury it a few feet down to the cottage.  Rock solid.  Done. No more 'black box`.   Grass will be back in a month.

Comment: Before I lay down cable, I'd like to test out a [power-line adaptor](https://www.hns-berks.co.uk/blogs/power-line-adapters-pros-and-cons), something I just learned about. The circuit to the cottage comes from the same panel as the house, so there's a chance this could work.

Comment: That is an option.  Good idea.